# What is the maximum circuit depth for Qiskit Aer Simulator?

Tags: qiskit, programming, circuit-construction

I'm running some simulator circuit on my computer, and I see that (using 3 qubits, and thousands of classical registers), the max cap seems to be about `qc.depth()` slightly less than 150000 before the kernel crash into oblivion (with or without `optimization_level = 3`, so I don't think that helps). I have plenty of RAM left and I don't see them filling up, and the circuits always only take a few seconds to run since I only do 1 shot so I doubt if it's a CPU problem. What is the cause of this, and is there any way to be able to run at higher depth? Thanks!